# A list of banned words for Event Titles

Tags: facebook-graph-api, filter

While testing my iOS app I got a funny error when creating an event with the following title:

`"Beer at White Trash Fast Food"`

and the error: `"(#100) Invalid event name specified: event_info-name"`

I promptly tried to create an event with the same title through the FB website and got the same error.

So, it seems like our very popular burger and beer joint in Berlin is banned by FB :)

Does anybody know if we can get a list of banned words?